# TFS Merge branch get conflicting files and commits

Tags: tfs

I have list of changesets in 1 branch of TFS that i need to merge to another branch in TFS.
Is there any way to get the list of conflicting changesets(even if TFS can resolve the conflict) based on the changesets that modified the same file but is not selected to be released?

Example:
1 file is modified twice in changeset 1 and 2
i want to release changeset 2.
Is there anything you can do on TFS to automatically tell me that changeset 1 changes are conflicting with this merge?

Comment: When you merge branch in Visual Studio, it will compare and identify the conflicts.. Another way you can use the [Difference Command- tf diff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/difference-command?view=vsts) to compare the changesets.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT: Thanks but i am aware of that. The diff needs to be done on case by case basis which is not efficient and since auto conflict resolution takes care of resolving them, you only get to know if the conflict cant be auto resolved. That is not enough.